# Computing permutations to find minimum time

Tags: c++

I need to suggest the minimum duration of work hours required to be done by the user.

If the user enters the data for future days as the following:

`1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 3, 9 and 1`, 4 would be the minimum work. I can't run a sort function on this list to find the minimum sum, because that would not take into account the sequence.

I am trying to build a simple portal for open source work distribution and I am new to programming.

Comment: Isnt the minimum duration 4 here? indices 2,4,6,9 is enough right? Please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming he can skip upto 2 days:

```
//n is the number of elements in the array
if(n<=3)
    //The minimum of the available numbers.
for(i=3;i<n;i++)
     array[i] += min(array[i-1],array[i-2],array[i-3]);
printf("%d",min(array[n-1],array[n-2],array[n-3]));
```

This wil provide you with the minimum required duration.

Comment: @TProgrammer: sorry that was a wrong code. See the updated version, for skipping upto 2 days.

Comment: How will it output several times? There is only one print statement.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

Now you wang to select **5** numbers from the list, and the first number must be one of first three items; once you select the first number, make the items after this number a new list, now use recursion to select (5-1=)4 numbers from the list. Every time you get 5 numbers, store them if it has smaller sum.

---

Sorry, this is a wrong answer. I misunderstood the question. This is the answer for selecting a certain number days from list. You can change it slightly to make it right, but with a low efficiency.